# View reminders checked today on iOS 13

Tags: reminders, ios

In previous version of iOS in Reminders app it was possible to view the list or reminders that were marked done grouped by day they were marked on in Scheduled "tab", so it was possible to view list of reminders that were marked today, yesterday and so on.

In iOS 13 if I show completed reminders in Scheduled, they are grouped by date for which they were scheduled, so it is not possible to view what was marked today.

Is there any way to get at least the list of reminders marked during today?